# Can not find linux/modversions.h

Tags: c, linux, makefile, driver

I am trying to install the driver for a serial device, and when I run the installation executable I get this error:

```
cc -DLINUX -c -DMODVERSIONS -DMODULE -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -pipe -m64 -mcmodel=kernel -I/usr/src/linux-3.8.0-27-generic/include -I/usr/src/linux-2.4/include -I/usr/src/linux/include -D__SMP__ npreal2.c
npreal2.c:40:31: **fatal error: linux/modversions.h: No such file or directory**
compilation terminated.
```

I don't find any solutions to this after searching the forums. I noticed that there is a modversions.h in the `/usr/src/linux-3.8.0-27-generic/include/config` , but not in the linux folder.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe you can make a soft link in the linux folder to the actual file? I am not sure how safe this is though.

Comment: @RSinghS I did try using a soft link, as a result, I bypassed the first errors. Now I get LOTS of errors from other header files ...

Comment: you can check if the linux folder itself is a symlink with ls -al
if it is not rename the folder with mv linux linux.bak
then make a symlink like this
ln -s /usr/src/linux-3.8.0-27-generic /usr/src/linux

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `-I /usr/src/linux-3.8.0-27-generic/include/config` as an argument to make?

or

Check if the header is a part of a certain package and update the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile modversions on your system by navigating to the linux directory (usually usr/src/linux).  Inside the linux source directory, there should be a file called Rules.make.  Inside this make file are build commands for making modversions.h.  You can make it by running:

```
 make update-modverfile
```

Now, while this will make the modversions.h library, if you compile it with a newer compiler than the libraries that this file relies on, many times you will get an error when trying to run a program that uses this header.  This then turns into a nightmare.

Comment: I don't find this file     Rules.make, and when I run the command I get     Configuration file ".config" not found! What else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Another method, I tried it successfully with Xubuntu 13.10:

1. Open /etc/default/grub
2. Add this Line and save it.

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=true"
   ```
3. reboot

   ```
   (no, sudo update-grub,ok)
   ```
4. open a terminal window, enjoy.

   ```
   locate modversions.h
   ```

   (Please don't forget modversion'**S**')